# Optimizar foreach PHP

Tags: php, optimización

En una clase un método ejecuta un ***foreach*** con el contenido que le viene por ejemplo de otro método, quiero saber **a nivel de rendimiento**, si es lo mismo recorrer los datos directamente o cargarlos en una variable y recorrerla, suelo usar el segundo método.

***Método 1. "Recorre" los datos directamente***

```
foreach ($this->getData() as $x) {
    //
}
```

***Método 2. Asigna los datos a una variable y luego la "recorre"***

```
$arr = $this->getData();
foreach ($arr as $x) {
    //
}
```

Entonces **¿hay variaciones en función de la versión de PHP, la estructura del array, si se obtienen los datos de un método, propiedad o de otra forma?**

#### Prueba con PHP 8.2.13

La memoria es siempre 389Kb, Máx. 20176Kb

Los tiempos de ejecución para el método 1:

```
0.089036s
0.082550s
0.079260s
0.083072s
0.081344s
// media: 0.0830524s
```

Los tiempos de ejecución para el método 2 (con variable):

```
0.086419s
0.107301s
0.079886s
0.087521s
0.102079s
// media: 0.0926412s
```

Código prueba:

```
<?php

class Foo
{

    private function getData(int $cycles = 100): array
    {
        $output = [];
        while ($cycles) {
            $cycles--;
            $output[]['time'] = time();
        }
        
        return $output;
    }


    public function run(int $cycles): void
    {
        $arr = $this->getData($cycles);
        foreach ($arr as $data) {

        // foreach ($this->getData($cycles) as $data) {

            var_dump($data['time']);
        }
    }
}

(new Foo)->run(50000);
```

Comment: Con PHP ni idea, pero yo he hecho esta prueba con otros lenguajes y es exactamente lo mismo, y es que cualquier compilador (o interprete) debería ser capaz de optimizar eso.  Intuyo por tu pregunta, que tu tienes la duda si la función `getData` es llamada en cada iteración, prueba agregar un `var_dump` dentro de ella y verás que se ejecuta una sola vez. Lo que siempre es más rápido (al menos en todos lo otros lenguajes que he probado) es un `for` con índice

Comment: hacer una asignacion a una variable declarada $arr o implementar un espacio anonimo para la asignacion, es imperseptible para el humano, y solo si los registros ocupan mas o menos espacio podras llegar al overflow de memoria ... aun asi no con 1 o 5 millones de datos dentro de una variable lo alcansaras ...

Comment: intenta con que la variable sea mas pesada ... metele un archivo pdf y a lo mejor detectaras algun diferencia mas tangible ...